# Server side pagination in JqGrid (no grid pager parameters)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, pagination

I have a jqGrid which requires server side pagination, I have to pass some search criteria's along with the request (POST), On Initial call I am able to fetch the results, but I am not able to find a way to send the grid's current page, index and size required for server side pagination as [mentioned here](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-use-jqgrid-with-asp-net-mvc/)

I used fiddle and the network tab to check if my request is generating the additional contents as mentioned in the above post, but couldn't find any

Below is my code

**JQGrid**

```
        $("#list").jqGrid({
        serializeGridData: function () {
            return {'data': JSON.stringify($('#searchInfo').serializeObject()) };
        },
        url: '/SearchUsers/SearchResult',
        mtype: 'POST',
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: {
            page: "currentPage",
            total: "totalPages",
            records: "total",
            root: "rows",
            cell: "",
            id: "0"
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        rowNum: 10,
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'FirstName',
        sortorder: "asc",
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        forceFit: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortable: false,
        colModel: [
            { label: 'ID', name: 'ID', align: "center", key: true, hidden: true, frozen: true },
            { label: 'First Name', name: 'FirstName', align: "left", sopt: ['cn'], frozen: true},
            { label: 'Last Name', name: 'LastName', align: "left", sopt: ['cn']},
            { label: 'Email Address', name: 'EmailAddress', align: "left", sopt: ['cn'] }
        ],
        viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data range and total records on the toolbar
        emptyrecords: "No records to view.",
        rowattr: Searchusers.RowFormatter,
    }).css("font-family", "Arial Narrow");
    $('#list').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn' });
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    $("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close").remove();
```

**My Json Data**

{
   "totalPages":"4",
   "currentPage":"1",
   "total":"35",
   "rows":[
      {
         "ID":"1",
         "FirstName":"a",
         "LastName":"a",
         "EmailAddress":"ab@cd-sg.com",
      },
      {
         "ID":"2",
         "FirstName":"s",
         "LastName":"k",
         "EmailAddress":"sk@co.com",
      },
      {
         "ID":"3",
         "FirstName":"K",
         "LastName":"G",
         "EmailAddress":"abc@abc-sg.com",
      },
      {
         "ID":"4",
         "FirstName":"as",
         "LastName":"asd",
         "EmailAddress":"asd@l.co",
      },
      {
         "ID":"5",
         "FirstName":"K",
         "LastName":"B",
         "EmailAddress":"KB@FB.com",
      }
.
.
.
30 more records
   ]
}

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `serializeObject` plugin myself, but I suppose it returns object with the properties which you want to send to the server. So you can try to replace the code of `serializeGridData` which you use to the following

```
serializeGridData: function (postdata) {
    return {data: JSON.stringify($.extend({},
        $("#searchInfo").serializeObject(), postdata))};
}
```

It should combine the standard properties of jqGrid from `postdata` with the object returned by `serializeObject` plugin.

Comment: @Oleg : Great answer, please can you tell a me how can I set statically the number of pages in jqgrid? I am calculating the nb of pages in server side code and send it back to front end code, Thanks.

Comment: @JadChahine: You are welcome! In case of server side paging you should return from the server response, which contains: the total number of pages (`total`), the total number of records/rows (`records`) and the number of the current page (`page`). See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) the description of the server responses.

Comment: one more question please, when i retrieve the first page from server side, the first page loads normally, but I am unable to click on the next button in jqgrid, it is read only, how can I tell the jqgrid that I have more pages to load? so I have to click on the next button many times until there is no record, Thanks.

Comment: @JadChahine: One have typically such behavior in the situation if jqGrid could not read `total` information from the server response. jqGrid supposes that it's the only page and the Next/Previous buttons of the pager will be deactivated. By the way, it's recommended to use `loadonce: true` and return **all the data at once** from the server if the total number of rows is not so much (less as 1000 or 10000). It simplify the server code. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 13 columns, 20 rows in the page and 4000 rows totally.